# How to pass a model without form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to hide some fields that I'm using into URL.

Actually I'm using

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { @model.Id })
```

It's work good but I want to hide them, and I don't have to use form.

Thanks to help me :-)

Comment: Correction: "You don't want to use POST", yeah?

Comment: Why would you want to hide them? A URL is used to have a complete description of a particular resource and you lose the intent by doing this.

Comment: @Lews I WANT to use POST, but without a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to hide anything from an URL. If it is in the URL it is visible. If you don't want to have it in the URL you could store this information on the server, using the Session for example.

Of course if this is not for security purposes, using a POST method would prevent this information from being sent into the URL.

Comment: Session could be solution but there will be lots of users so I don't think it's the best idea. Security purposes is good too

Comment: No, session is never a good idea. I don't even know why I am mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here about how the web works. HTTP verbs exist for a reason. GET is for retrieving a resource; POST is for creating a new resource or performing some *action* server-side. It's inappropriate to simply retrieve a resource via POST, which is why the browser has no native ability to do that.

Besides, the idea that you're somehow "hiding" something via POST is preposterous. The data in a POST is just as visible as the data in a GET to prying eyes. You achieve nothing.

More to the point, there's no reason to even try. If you're trying to hide the id because you believe you gain some sort of security from doing that, you're wrong. The id is entirely contextual: it has no meaning outside of the database, and if someone obtains access to your database, having the id of a record there is the least of your issues.